# Extract data from NetCDF file with tripolar projection for lat & long coordinates

Tags: python, coordinate-system, netcdf, extract, climate

I have coordinates obtained from Google Maps (latitude and longitude). I also downloaded a number of NetCDF4 files for different years and months that contain sea surface temperature (SST) from the link below. This data is related to ORAS5 global ocean reanalysis monthly data. https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-oras5?tab=form

Now I want to extract the sea surface temperature data related to these coordinates from the NetCDF4 files. Datum for Google Maps is WGS84 and Projection is a ”web Mercator”. The projection for the NetCDF4 files is also “Tripolar model grid”.

If I need to change the NC files projection to Web Mercator, how is it done?

In general, what should be done to correctly extract SST data in NetCDF files for Google Maps coordinates?